# Antivirus clash with program

Tags: c#, release, antivirus

Just finished my first proper program, I have now `published` it so it can be run through an `.EXE` rather than a visual studio. The issue I am coming up against is that my `antivirus` views the application as a `threat` and constantly scans it and prevents it access to run. Would I need to build a security certificate to prevent this? Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Owen

Comment: Which antivirus are you using?

Comment: Which antivirus progrgam?

Comment: avast, im just looking to stop the it preventing me access. even if i run as administrator it prevents it from running. (the programs a CSV to SQL converter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [False positive detection of c# .net program by anti-virus as trojan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683518/false-positive-detection-of-c-sharp-net-program-by-anti-virus-as-trojan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the antivirus program to exclude it from considering as dangerous. Check out the menus of the antivirus checker.
This happens very often when you are scanning the disk to find things. But the sensitivity depends on the virus scanner.

Signing your app with trusted certificate also eliminates suspicion in most of antivirus progs. But this will not work for some antivirus like Norton Internet Security etc.

Depending on the anti virus, you can exclude/White list them.